# How to end the threading task?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

How can I end my threading task? My code is like this:

```py
import threading

def printit():
    threading.Timer(5.0, printit).start()
    print('Hello!')
printit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import threading

def printit():
    thread  = threading.Timer(1.0, printit)
    thread.start()
    x = 'your_stopping_condition'
    if x == 'your_stopping_condition':
        thread.cancel()
    else:
        print('Hello!')
printit()
```

Comment: Wanted to ask if this recursive thread setup is the best way to execute this logic

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
def printit(stop):
    thread  = threading.Timer(5.0, printit)
    thread.start()
    print('Hello!')
    x = 'your_stopping_condition'
    if x == 'your_stopping_condition':
        t.cancel()
printit()
```

Comment: Well there is a mistake in this above code, but it helped me answer this question.